# How to return return object(s) that gives me document as well as reports details

Tags: django, django-orm

I have multiple documents and each document has multiple supporting reports. How do i return object(s) that provides me information of both document and the report

One solution is to return all the document objects and iterate over reports for each object (slow). What I am currently doing is returning document object and I have a separate page which loads onclick and returns the corresponding reports

models.py looks like this:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    path = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    date_of_submission = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    department = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

 class Report(models.Model):
    document_code = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    path = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

Expected:
object(s) that has information for both report objects and document object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ManyToManyField` in your models.

Check this [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) please.

```py
 class Report(models.Model):
    document_code = models.ManyToManyField(Document)
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way? as there are many reports for a single document

Comment: Please check that link I shared it to you. It mentioned a nice example that you need. @Rishabh

Comment: Yes! I figured it out by trying a few examples. Thanks a lot!